# How can I get the type of T from the type of T?

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to rewrite a framework my organization uses into .Net Core; specifically the Generic Repository at this point.
I am stuck on the following issue.

We have a BaseEntity defined as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T> : IBaseEntity<T>
{
    [Key]
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}
```

it inherits from Interface:

```
public interface IBaseEntity<T>
{
    [Key]
    T Id { get; set; }
}
```

I define an Entity like this:

```
public class Employee : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string OfficeBureau { get; set; }
    public string Supervisor { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    // TODO:
    // public virtual ICollection<Case> Cases { get; set; }
}
```

AppContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Repo Interface:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T>
    where T : BaseEntity<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();     // No need to async IQueryable
    Task<T> GetAsync(int id);
    Task<T> InsertAsync(T entity);
    Task UpdateAsync(T entity);
    Task DeleteAsync(T entity);

    #region Possible TODOs:
    // Should this one go in the Service Layer?
    // Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

    //Task AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    //Task RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    #endregion

    Task SaveAsync();
}
```

Repo implementation:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
    where T: BaseEntity<T>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private DbSet<T> _entities;

    public GenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entities = context.Set<T>();
    }

    // No need to async IQueryable
    public IQueryable<T> GetAll() => _entities.AsQueryable();

    public Task<T> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Now look at the signiture of:

```
public Task<T> GetAsync(int id)
```

Here is my dilemma.
What is the  point of setting up all entities to inherit from BaseEntity so that we can have an id of int or guid on the fly if we search on a hard coded int type for GetById or GetAsync here?

Is this a common pattern? Is this a short coming of the original author of the code?   Or am I missing something in this pattern?
If this is a short coming, is there a way to get the type of the entity id on the fly through reflection and search by it?  And if so would it take a performance hit?

Should I just take away the generic for the id type on BaseEntity and just force users of the framework to always make all entities have the same type of ID throughout an application using the framework?

Other than that the main purpose of the generic repo holds up.  Not having to write a repo with the same methods for every entity.
Any advice appreciated here.

Comment: Your title doesn't appear to match your question(s).

Comment: The EntityFramework team itself dealt with the same problem and they exposed the `DbContext.Find()` method (which is actually "get by id") that is expecting an `object id` as a parameter (see https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/DbContext.cs#L1258).

Comment: To clarify if T in GenericRepo refers to say, Employee, and Employee derives from BaseEntity<T> where T is the type of the entity's Id, then I'm saying T for "Employee : BaseEntity" is nested in GenericRepository<T>.  These are two different Ts.  I played around with "GenericRepository<T, TID> and then BaseEntity<TId>.  Sorry about the naming of the question.  

And in looking at the EF team comment above, interesting, but now seeing to apply this or how it will solve my problem.

Comment: @Sam, The way to apply it would simply be `await return _entities.FindAynsc(id)` when `id` is an `object`.

Comment: I just can't wrap my head around this.  Do I have to change any of my above code? Or will it work as is?

Comment: ham770 - The problem is, in my signiure: "public async Task<T> FindAsync(long id)", how do I make long generic?  I guess I could make it object so it can take anything.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what the commenters are suggesting, define it as an object.

My thought was to just overload the GetAsync for allowable id types, so: GetAsync(int id) and GetAsync(Guid id), and GetAsync(anyothertypeyouwanttouseasyouridentitycolumn id)

Comment: I think I'm starting to see now.  In that case my hunch was right and we don't need to define the BaseEntity as a generic like this: BaseEntity<T>.  Because the "where T : BaseEntity<T>" constraint on GenericRepository I don't think is doing what the original author of our framework thinks.  T for BaseEntity is not like <int> or <guid> like I think he thinks.  It is going to be like <Employee> or some other entity. So BaseEnitity<Employee> doesn't make sense.  I've stripped it down like this and I have some Web API working with IGenericRepository<Employee> being passed to the context. It works

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're getting confused with what "T" is. You're most of the way there but you are switching the "context" of the T half way through your code. At first it refers to the type of the "Id", then you make it the type of "Model"

Try this instead. I'll do a bit of renaming to make it more clear rather than using T.

Your base entity should look like the following :

```
public interface IBaseEntity<Key>
{
    [Key]
    Key Id { get; set; }
}
```

Employee should essentially be the same thing :

```
public class Employee : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public string OfficeBureau { get; set; }
    public string Supervisor { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    // TODO:
    // public virtual ICollection<Case> Cases { get; set; }
}
```

Now your generic repository. Now look carefully at the following code. This is where you went wrong.

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T, Key>
    where T : BaseEntity<Key>
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();     // No need to async IQueryable
    Task<T> GetAsync(Key id);
    Task<T> InsertAsync(T entity);
    Task UpdateAsync(T entity);
    Task DeleteAsync(T entity);
}
```

So you notice that I am now passing in TWO generic types. One is the model type that this repository is calling, the other is the type of key that the model uses.

Your generic repository should look like the following

```
public class GenericRepository<T, Key> : IGenericRepository<T, Key>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private DbSet<T> _entities;

    public GenericRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entities = context.Set<T>();
    }

    // No need to async IQueryable
    public IQueryable<T> GetAll() => _entities.AsQueryable();

    public Task<T> GetAsync(Key id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then when you create an actual repository, it might look like the following.

```
public class UserRepository : GenericRepository<User, int>, IGenericRepository<User, int>, IUserRepository
{
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I had realized this and tried to work through exactly as you say here.  I had named mine like this:
"public interface IGenericRepository<T, TId>
    where T : BaseEntity<TId>".
But now follow it all the way through.  In the repo when I go to use the FindAsync method, I don't think you can use a generic as the Type of incoming parameter:
I think this will complain:
"public Task<T> GetAsync(TId id)"
or
"public Task<T> GetAsync(Key id)"
But, I will work on this some more.  Does anyone have a complete example of a repo defining a  CRUD method using an incoming generic type?